Change the default app to open mail in Ubuntu 24.04
I finally installed Ubuntu 24.04 with only one partition (/). Now, I am in the process of installing apps and so on. I already changed my default app for Web to "Edge." Now, I would like to change "Mail" so that it will open Gmail from the Edge Browser, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Can anyone guide me to work out command-line instruction to do that?
